# Debugging a Python package when running on docker container

Tags: pycharm, docker-desktop

I'm using Docker Desktop to run a container locally and encountering issues with a particular package within my application. When debugging in PyCharm, I found myself stepping through empty lines, leading me to discover that there's a discrepancy between the code displayed in PyCharm and the code actually being executed.

Is there a method to configure PyCharm to synchronize and display the exact versions of the packages installed within the Docker container?

Executing `pip install -r requirements.txt` on my local machine did not resolve this issue. Moreover, this approach would be impractical for me since my packages require frequent updates.